# Liquibase integrated with a Tapestry and Hibernate: initial schema creation step

Tags: java, hibernate, tapestry, liquibase

I have the project based on `Tapestry` framework. It uses `Hibernate` as ORM library.

My classes are mapped to database using `annotations`.

I would like to integrate `Liquibase` into my project to be able to maintance database state, doing version updates.

What I have done till this moment is the following steps:

1) I've created service pair: `LiquibaseService` -> `LiquibaseServiceImpl`.

`LiquibaseSerivce` has method `public void update()`, which creates independent `DataSource` from `hibernate.cfg.xml` configuration and finally does `liquibase.update("production");`

2) I've added binding to this service in `AppModule`:

`binder.bind(LiquibaseService.class, LiquibaseServiceImpl.class).eagerLoad();`

3) I've added `initMyApplication` method to `AppModule` which starts `Liquibase` update:

```
@Startup
public static void initMyApplication(Logger logger, LiquibaseService liquibaseService) {
    logger.info("Updating database by liquibase service...");
    liquibaseService.update();
    logger.info("update-db done.");
}
```

---

All this works fine on production, where initial scheme was already created: I can comfortable drop tables, columns and so on.

But the issue is that I can not create new scheme from zero (using `Liquibase`) when deploying application to a new server: `Hibernate` starts independently ans complains, that there aren't any tables mapped to my class in the scheme.

**How can I slow down `Hibernate` starting until that moment when `Liquibase` will finish its job?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using @Startup you can do something like this

```
    public static void contributeRegistryStartup(
     final Logger logger, final LiquibaseService liquibaseService,
     OrderedConfiguration<Runnable> configuration)
    {
        configuration.add("Liquibase", new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                logger.info("Updating database by liquibase service...");
                liquibaseService.update();
                logger.info("update-db done.");
            }
        }, "after:HibernateStartup");
    }
```

Comment: you mean, that `Tapestry` will automatically inject `Logger` and `LiquibaseService`, will it?

Comment: TapestryIOC injects all Parameters into the AppModule#contribute method and you can always access final variables from an inner anonymous class.

Comment: yes, it actually works, I checked it. Thanks, it is an interesting decision. I'll +1 your answer, but I'm yet interesting how to do this using annotations. Or it is impossible?

Comment: You can't do it yet. You can file a jira though